# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3556, 3000]

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

iam doing image classification project while doing train test split i got this error ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3556, 3000]

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, data_target, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
```

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace and a minimal reproductible example.

Answer (score 0):

Your `X` and `data_target` are of different lengths. You can trim `X` like this:

```
X = X[:3000]
```

so that `X` and `data_target` are both length of 3000.